# Path for images issue

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I created a rails project, downloaded a bootstrap theme, and moved the html, css, javascript and images into the corresponding folders in my rails app. I opened the rails app in sublime 2 and searched for 'img' tag to update the path for the images. Currently my images are in the following path: app/assets/images/

```
<img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="app/assets/images/portfolio-1.jpg">
```

Above is the img tag for one of my images that I want to display. I have removed 'app' and 'assets' from the path and it still won't display.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rails `image_tag` helper

```
<%= image_tag("portfolio-1.jpg", class: "img-portfolio img-responsive") %>
```

or you can simply do like this

```
<img src="/assets/portfolio-1.jpg" class="img-portfolio img-responsive">
```

for more info check here http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

Comment: You beautiful beautiful soul! It worked perfect! Been trying to figure that out for the past hour. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `html`, you don't need to call the full path and it should be like this:

```
<img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="assets/portfolio-1.jpg">
```

And if you use rails helper:

```
<%= image_tag 'portfolio-1.jpg', class: "img-portfolio img-responsive" %>
```